Applying deterministic operators on i.i.d. random variables from the same probability distribution - what is conserved?
I have a collection of i.i.d. random variables xi, sampled from the same (possibly unknown) probability distribution, say P. Now I apply a deterministic operator on these i.i.d. random variables, e.g., the norm operator, say F.
I believe that now F(xi) are again i.i.d. random variables sampled from the same (possibly unknown and possibly different to P) probability distribution. Is my belief correct and if yes, I would like to support it with a reference.

This comes down to nothing other than the definition of random variable and probability distribution, so you scarcely need a reference! What definitions of those two concepts do you know?

@whuber thanks for the pointer, that's a great answer, probably worth it to share to the OP

Thanks, @Alberto.  Abdullah: Alberto is referring to the demonstration here on CV that functions of independent RVs are independent.  I hope it is obvious that when two variables have the same distribution then any function (applied to each separately) yields variables with the same distribution, too, thereby completing the answer.

Thanks Alberto and whuber. I will look into it and try to formulate a satisfactory answer. I need to look a bit more into the basics of probability and measure. Thanks!

Maybe a further question: Does this function need to be Borel measurable?
In my case my random variables are coefficients that define a function. I want to know whether the norm of that function which is defined by an inner product is also a random variable? I am not sure if this norm function is Borel measurable as the function space is not necessarily seperable.
